# Почему FireBase Auth не работает в apk

Tags: android, firebase, sha1

Мне нужно зайти с помощью email И paasword в активити, для этого я использую FirebaseAuth, когда я запускаю приложение по отладке, вход работает, но когда я создаю apk файл и устонавливаю на телефон реализовать вход не получается, выводится вот такая ошибка что меня блокируют:

```
com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ Requests from this Android client application com.application.mysuccessful are blocked. ]
```

Я поискал в интернете там говорится что мой ключ sha1 работает только для отладки что то типа такого, но конкретного решения я не нашел, скажите пж как мне получить этот ключ. И еще если я выложу это приложение в таком состоянии в Play Market будет ли работать этот вход? СпасибО!